# AWS S3 & IAM - Define policy where user have only access (read) to certain folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get a user the permission only to download from certain folder.

My S3 bucket is called 'bucket-data' and I have 3 folders with content.

```
bucket-data
    folder01
    folder02
    folder03
```

How can I define a policy that the user can only download from folder 01 and folder3

As of right now I've set this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-data/folder01/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
sftp> ls -la
Couldn't read directory: Permission denied
```

Here is there tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aq4y5B1jjMg

And the only thing I get to work up until now is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Would you like IAM user specific permissions, or public read for everyone?

Comment: I will attach the policy to a AWS Transfer sftp user and different users should have different permission to download data (via sftp) from defined folders in the policies I create for each user. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-data"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-data/folder01/*", "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-data/folder03/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ListBucket` action of S3 should be acting on the bucket resource, NOT on object level. Therefore, in order to make this work, you need to add another statement.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-data/folder01/*"]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-data",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "folder01/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still getting the same error: Couldn't read directory: Permission denied. And I have two warnings when the opening the policy 1. Specify accesspoint resource ARN for the GetAccessPointPolicy and 1 more action. 2. Specify bucket resource ARN for the GetBucketLocation and 22 more actions.

Comment: And can you showcase it for two folders? folder01 and folder03 ?

Comment: @PhilippM `"s3:prefix": ["folder01/*", "folder03/*"]`

Comment: It's not working though, still getting message: Couldn't read directory: Permission denied. And 2 warnings.